# Convert date to Month Year using Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, datetime

I have a Date() object in Javascript. How can I convert it to show "Month Year" (example: Oct 2021).

I tried the following code and it works too. However, I have to convert a lot of dates to this format and it has performance issues.

```
  const date = new Date();
  const month = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short' });
  const year = date.toLocaleString('default', { year: 'numeric' });
```

Note: I don't want to use JQuery or other libraries.

Comment: "*it has performance issues*" What kind of performance issues? In comparison to what?

Comment: If I use date.toDateString() then it takes 500 ms compared to "month year" takes 2 seconds. However, date.toDateString() does not give the "month year" format.

Comment: `takes 2 seconds`...not as far as I can see, it seems to be instant: https://jsfiddle.net/fjbv20na/

Comment: 2 seconds to process about 25,000 records. If I change it to date.toDateString(), it takes 500 ms to process those 25,000 records.

Comment: How can you rationally compare a method which doesn't return what you need it to, versus a method that *does* meet your requirements? `date.toLocaleString()` isn't faster than `Array.push()`, but they don't do the same thing. It's not rational to compare apples with oranges.

Comment: What if you do both of them at once: `const formatted = date.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'short', year: 'numeric' });`?

Comment: umm correct, what I meant to say is there must be some other way to get the "Month year" which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks Joe, it would save half the time I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is such a concern, why not just reduce some complexity and use [`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)/[`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) and manually map the abbreviated month names?

```js
const date = new Date();
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
console.log(months[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getFullYear())
```

It's [provably faster than the other methods posited here](https://jsbench.me/zgkuo6xtz3/1), even with the requirement to declare `months`.

Comment: Thanks @esqew - it fixed the performance issue while still returning the same result. Not sure why it has so many negative votes and how can I improve it. Thanks a lot for your help.